# Flutter unselect text on click

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am using `SelectableText` widget in my website. When I select a text with my mouse, the only way to unselect it is to click on the `SelectableText`.

How can I unselect text when I click anywhere on the screen ? Which is a classic behavior for a website.

```dart
class MainPageWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: SelectableText("This is a selectable text"),
    );
  }
}
```

But if I remove the `Scaffold` to keep the `SelectableText` only, it works. But then the text is displayed in a weird way if there is no `Scaffold`.

> I am using Google Chrome on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I'm not facing such any issue, it is working perfectly fine. Can you include the code-snippet to reproduce the same issue?

Comment: I have edited my question to add a very simple example @YeasinSheikh

Comment: I've tested on win10 chrome, and it is working fine with scaffold and using nested widget.  You can try testing on different device to check if it is a device specific issue.

Comment: anyone facing this?

Comment: I am facing this problem.

Comment: @JamesLloyd Yeah me too. My answer was working when I posted it but it is no longer the case. I think it is not something we can solve. We have to wait for Flutter maintainers to fix it

Comment: @Kantine if we look at the function called within SelectableText when it is tapped there is a way that could be called when a tap is registered anywhere on the screen using the GestureDetector widget (wrapped around the Scaffold)?

Comment: facing the same issue on Flutter: 2.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution came with Flutter 3.3 and `SelectionArea` widget. There is no longer need for `SelectableText`. Just wrap your `Scaffold` with a `SelectableArea` and use `Text` instead of `SelectableText`.

See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectionArea-class.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing my flutter channel to go to stable release:

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

Edit: this answer was working when I posted it, but it is no longer the case. I guess the problem comes from something internal to flutter.